# What is the probability of an observation with a given level of similarity, across a set of attributes, to any individual in a known population?

Tags: r, probability, statistical-significance, combinatorics

I'm attempting to identify individuals sampled from a known set, using observations of the attributes I know for the individuals.  I have an algorithm to find the closest match already; what I'm trying to do next is find a measure for how likely it would be to get that match or closer to any individual in the set by random chance.  I think I have some pieces already but a few steps have me stumped.  I included what I have so far below.

### An overview of the problem

Each observation I make consists of eight measurements of separate attributes, where each measurement consists of an unordered pair of values that is always drawn (possibly repeating) from the possible set of values for that attribute from the population.  The pairs of values for all individuals in the population are known.  The values themselves happen to be numeric, but for my comparisons here I don't think that matters and I can think of them as arbitrary values from a set.  These could also be thought of as 16 attributes instead if that makes the math simpler, but either way the order for each pair doesn't matter.

In a perfect world I would make a perfect observation, all measurements would be trustworthy, and I'd see what individual matches those exact values.  But, the measurements I make may be incorrect (but still taken from the set of possible values) or missing some of the time.  If I'm comparing an observation with an individual and trying to see if that's a likely match, I want to know how likely I am to see that happen randomly, and see how that likelihood increases as the number of mismatches from my observation to any given individual increases.  (I'm counting mismatches within each pair, so (141,161) compared to (161,170) has one mismatch.)  I'd like to be able to say not just "observation 1 is identical to Individual A across the 8 attributes except for 2 mismatches," but also "there is an X% probability that we would see an observation within 2 mismatches or closer to any individual in our population simply by selecting randomized attribute values."

### More specifically

I have 142 individuals, with this many possible values for each of those eight paired attributes:

- 9
- 6
- 12
- 9
- 17
- 14
- 12
- 9

In my R example code below, `num_vals_per_attr` is effectively `c(9, 6, 12, 9, 17, 14, 12, 9)`.

Just for an example, a known individual might have these values:

- 141, 161
- 196, 200
- 190, 190
- 298, 302
- 252, 256
- 322, 322
- 237, 241
- 287, 295

And I could have an observation I'm comparing that to that looks like this:

- 177, 161 <- one mismatch
- 196, 200
- 190, 190
- 298, 302
- 252, 248 <- one mismatch
- 322, 322
- 237, 241
- 287, 300 <- one mismatch

So this observation would be within three mismatches of the individual shown.  Those values that are mismatched do exist for other individuals in the population, just not the one shown here.  The individuals may be close to each other but we can assume they won't be identical.

### What I have so far

To start with I thought about the probability of seeing any particular single combination of values in any single observation.  I dropped the paired aspect to simplify things and just thought of it as 16 separate measurements all independently pulled from separate sets of possible values.

In this case I think the probability of any given combination is just 1 to the total number of possible combinations (against).  Since the attribute are independent entities I can just take the product of the numbers of possible values per attribute to get the number of possible combinations.

If I allow one "mismatch," I'm looking at however many observations I can think up that allow the first entry to take any value, or the second, and so on, and comparing *that* sum to the number of total possible combinations. That's the equivalent of saying I should sum up these things:

- (number of possible values for attribute 1) * (number of total combinations of other attributes = 1 since I'm not varying them)
- (number of possible values for attribute 2) * (number of total combinations of other attributes = 1 again)
- (etc.)

So I'll just end up adding up the numbers of values for each attribute.  If I allow two mismatches, I'll need to look at all combinations of pairs of attributes, and sum:

- (number of possible values for attribute 1) * (number of possible values for attribute 2)
- (number of possible values for attribute 2) * (number of possible values for attribute 3)
- (etc. for attribute 1)
- (number of possible values for attribute 2) * (number of possible values for attribute 4)
- (number of possible values for attribute 2) * (number of possible values for attribute 5)
- (etc. for attribute 2, except the one we already did)
- (etc.)

So what it looks to me like I'm doing is n-choose-k, where n is my number of attributes (16 as I'm doing it here, though I'm ignoring the pairing) and k is however many mismatches I allow (zero through 16).  If I take the products of these combinations for each case as shown and sum them up I'll get the number of possible attribute combinations within "k" mismatches of any arbitrary combination.  If I then divide that number by the grand total of possible combinations, I'll get the proportion of possible combinations that could come up with "k" mismatches.  I'm working this out in R, and I came up with this to tally up that numerator:

```
sum(combn(num_vals_per_attr, k, prod))
```

With the denominator just being that same calculation, but where everything is allowed to vary:

```
sum(combn(num_vals_per_attr, length(num_vals_per_attr), prod))
```

That gives me the same value as just taking the product of all entries in `num_vals_per_attr`, but I liked the fact that the same combn expression gives simply "1" for `k=0` all the way up to the maximum value for `k=length(num_vals_per_attr)`.  Since I'm allowing k mismatches *or closer*, I think that thankfully avoids the complication of having to exclude certain combinations based on a specific comparison to an individual (right?)

So now I *think* what I have what is the probability that I could take a randomly-shuffled combination of attributes and arrive within k mis-matches of any particular (single) other possible combination.  That's about as far as I can get.  I've ignored the fact that I have eight pairs of unordered values rather than 16 ordered ones, and I'm not sure how to take into account the fact that I'm looking a set of individuals and comparing to the closest match for a given observation, so I'm not really just looking in the neighborhood of a single point in the arbitrary configuration space of possible values. That is to say, if I have twice as many individuals scattered across my configuration space, the likelihood of a false match should goes up.  But can I get away with just scaling my values linearly by number of individuals, or it something else?  I haven't been able to reason that out.

I've reviewed a few similar-looking questions but haven't spotted anything that seems to quite fit this situation.  Thanks for any suggestions!